# How To Detect Option Change When Using selectBoxIt JQuery Plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

### [Live Demo On JSBin](http://jsbin.com/bemokulawo/edit?html,output)

```
  $(".abc123").selectBoxIt();

  $(document).on('mousedown', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).parent().parent().parent().parent().children(":first").hasClass('abc123')) {
      var anchor = $(this).find('a');
      var test = $(anchor).text();
      alert($(this).parent().attr('class'));
    }
  })
```

The above is a snippet of my much larger script where I am trying to apply additional functions mousedown section. I'm using the [selectBoxIt](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/index.html) JQuery plugin which will turn any basic select option list into a more prettier version.

### What is my best solution to detect a new option change?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you're using a plugin to style the `select`, you can still hook to the `change` event of the underlying element, like this:

```
$(".abc123").selectBoxIt().change(function() {
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

I'm not certain exactly what your current code is attempting to do as `this` is the `document` and therefore attempting to get the `parent()` is moot, however the above code will at least get you the current value of the select when it's changed.

Comment: That is absolutely fantastic! I've still so much to learn... Thank you for your help

Comment: No problem, glad to help.